# SQL query to tell when server no longer has the requested starting point

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

I have a master-slave setup using postgres 9.5.3 and got the following error in my postgres log

"could not start WAL streaming: ERROR:  requested starting point 0/D000000 on timeline 2 is not in this server's history"

I would like to know if there is sql query that can tell me that my server no longer has the requested starting point so I will be able to automatically start full copy of the master data directory.

Thanks
Avi

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can get this information with SQL; you'd have to examine the contents of `pg_xlog`.

Wouldn't it be a better solution to use a [*replication slot*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION-SLOTS) to ensure that WAL is kept long enough?